# Highest Count with a group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having an absolute brain fade

```
SELECT p.ProductCategory, f.ProductSubCategory, COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM Sales f
JOIN Products p ON f.ProductSubCategory = p.ProductSubCategory
GROUP BY p.ProductCategory, f.ProductSubCategory
ORDER BY 1,3 DESC
```

This shows me the count for each ProductSubCategory, I would like to see only the highest ProductSubCategory per ProductCategory.

[image]

I wish to see (I don't care about the Count value)

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a job for a window function!

Comment: What if you use `max()` function instead of `count()`

Comment: How do you define "*highest*"?

Comment: by highest, i mean the most instances in the sales table.

Comment: Can you post some sample data along with desired result.

Comment: I think a nested subquery on max of sub categories for each category is what you want here.

Comment: rank should do the trick. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to do this.  One involves joining the results back to themselves and using the `max` aggregate.  But since you are using SQL Server, you can use `ROW_NUMBER` to achieve the same result:

```
with cte as (
    select p.productcategory, p.ProductSubCategory, COUNT(*) cnt, 
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by p.productcategory order by count(*) desc) rn 
    from products p 
        join sales s on p.ProductSubCategory = s.ProductSubCategory
    group by p.productcategory, p.ProductSubCategory
    )
select * 
from cte 
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You already got the answer, Please see the following code to. It may help you.

```
SELECT  p.ProductCategory, 
        f.ProductSubCategory,
        COUNT(*) AS Cnt
FROM    Sales f
JOIN    Products p ON f.ProductSubCategory = p.ProductSubCategory
JOIN    (
        SELECT  p.ProductCategory, 
                f.ProductSubCategory, 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY    p.ProductCategory,
                                                    f.ProductSubCategory 
                                    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) [Row]
        FROM    Sales f
        JOIN    Products p ON f.ProductSubCategory = p.ProductSubCategory) Lu 
        ON      P.ProductCategory = Lu.ProductCategory
        AND     f.ProductSubCategory = Lu.ProductSubCategory
WHERE   Lu.Row = 1
GROUP   By  p.ProductCategory, 
            f.ProductSubCategory
```